# Why do I get a type inference error for only one side of a range bound?

Tags: rust, type-inference

I am solving the [SPOJ PRIME1 - Prime Generator](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) problem:

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn is_prime(n: u64) -> bool {
    let bound = (n as f64).sqrt() as u64;
    for i in 2..bound + 1 {
        if n % i == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut s).expect("Error");
    let n: u32 = s.trim().parse().unwrap();

    for i in 0..n {
        let mut s = String::new();
        stdin().read_line(&mut s).expect("Error");
        let t: Vec<&str> = s.trim().split(" ").collect();
        let mut left = t[0].parse().unwrap();
        let right = t[1].parse().unwrap();
        if left == 1 {
            left += 1;
        }
        for j in left..right + 1 {
            if is_prime(j) {
                println!("{}", j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compilation fails due to this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:23:13
   |
23 |         let right = t[1].parse().unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^
   |             |
   |             consider giving `right` a type
   |             cannot infer type for `_`
```

Why is the error message about the `right` variable? Why is nothing said about the `left` variable? They appear in almost the same context. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `+ 1` in `left..right + 1` seems to be confusing the compiler. It works without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging a problem, it's very useful to create a [MCVE](/help/mcve). This is a technique that will greatly aid you as you continue to learn about programming. Here's an example for this case:

```
fn main() {
    let left = "0".parse().unwrap();
    let right = "1".parse().unwrap();

    for j in left..right + 1 {
        let j2: u64 = j;
    }
}
```

They do take practice, however. See the revision history for a reduction that was a little too minimal.

> They appear in almost the same context.

Yes, and how they are *different* should be a clue. What is different about `left` and `right` in the above code? There are two things I see:

1. `right` has a value added to it. In Rust, [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) can be overloaded on different types for the two things being added. This means that the pair of input types determines the output type. However, you cannot "work backwards" from a result type to input types because there can be more than one pair of input types that results in a `u64`. The four permutations of (`u64`, `&u64`) is one example.
2. `left` occurs first. If you reduce all the way to this code, you still only get one error, whichever occurs first:

   ```
   fn main() {
       let left = "0".parse().unwrap();
       let right = "1".parse().unwrap();
   }
   ```

   As for **why**, I'm not fully sure. However, cascading errors is a common hard thing for compilers to report. In this case, I'd believe that type inference fails once, so any subsequent inference is likely to be wrong, so the compiler stops there and reports the error.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good MCVE. In the original code, the compiler knows the type of `j` is `u64` and is able to deduce the type of `left` from this, but not the type of `right`. Perhaps this is a better MCVE: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=286c89a748791eee13303b352a75efa9&version=stable. Note that it compiles without the `+1`.

Comment: @interjay good call; and that gives a little bit more of a concrete rationale as well.

Comment: @interjay although I'm surprised that it infers that `left` should be a `u64`; I guess if someone else implemented `Range` such that multiple types yielded `u64` it wouldn't anymore.